# Embeded WebBrowser Control for WPF with WebRTC support

Tags: .net, wpf, webrtc, awesomium, getusermedia

I have a WPF application, and I need peer to peer connection between application instance and page in web-browser. I want to use embedded web browser control and load html+js working with getUserMedia function, but I can't find working solution. Standard Web Browser control based on IE generates js errors for getUserMedia function and Awesomium SDK havsn't support of WebRTC too (http://answers.awesomium.com/questions/1415/how-is-it-possible-to-use-a-webcam-with-awesomium.html).
Can you advice me, how to solve problem with WebRTC connection between WPF Application and page in web-browserl?

Answer (score 2):

[Chromium Embedded Framework](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/) has a [WPF binding library](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) available. They claim that it supports the HTML5 technologies available in Google Chrome web browser.

Comment: Chromium does not have full WebRTC support (source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27930375/is-webrtc-codes-already-in-the-chromium-codes/27936683#27936683)

Comment: Yes. No browsers fully support WebRTC yet, it is very new/immature. See http://iswebrtcreadyyet.com

Answer (score 0):

There is another Chromium-based solution that supports WebRTC and provides a WPF control: https://www.teamdev.com/dotnetbrowser

In addition, this product provides API to work with DOM and a JS bridge that allows to implement two-way communication between your application and the web page.

It is commercial, but there are free open-source and academic licences.

Answer (score 0):

there is another good web browser available to use in WPF

https://www.essentialobjects.com/Products/WebBrowser/Default.aspx

they have very great support and nicely work done, entire chrome browser inside your WPF/WinForms app :-)