# Is webRTC codes already in the chromium codes?

Tags: webrtc

I'm trying to study webRTC and want to learn about how it encodes and transport the media stream.

Are codes of this part of webRTC already included in the chromium source codes?
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxBuildInstructions

Thanks~!

Comment: Are you trying to build a Chromium with WebRTC yourself? On what platforms? If yes - I'm very interested in hearing how you do this...

Answer (score 3):

yes and no.

- The core of webrtc (including all the transport) is in the third party libwertc code, you can find information at webrtc.org.
- The codec and other libraries are shared with Chrome, and libwebrtc import a copy of chromium when building from source. THe exact list of libs that are shared are in [this file](http://webrtc.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/setup_links.py)
- The "capturer" is in the chrome code, more info [there](http://www.chromium.org/audio-video).

Comment: Thanks a lot~! The links are really helpful~!

Comment: BTW, are these 2 conjectures possible?...(1) to adapt webRTC media stream transportation to QUIC;...(2) to provide an interface for upper layer user to assign a specific Codec while doing encoding for captured images.

Comment: (1) - No. Quick is an evolution over HTTP, the media streams in webRTC use (S)RTP. Different protocols.
(2) - Yes. The new API influenced by the work of the ORTC Community Group will allow to choose the codec. However, you cannot add your own codec, you can only choose between those provided by the browser. In November Google announced they would support H.264, but did not provide any ETA.

Comment: I have to correct myself here: there is a quick, hacky implementation of webrtc on QUIC by the google team in the review website: https://webrtc-codereview.appspot.com/20199004/

Comment: Thank you, Alex! Yes the webpage you mentioned is what I'm thinking, I haven't checked them all, but will do it tonight. And I will also check the ORTC community group for the API, sounds great~!

Comment: For ORTC, you might want to wait. I just meant there will be in webRTC 1.0 a new API called RTCRTPSender (and receiver) among others, that will allow you to specify things like codec on a track by track basis. The idea comes from work done within ORTC, that's why I mention them (to give them proper credit) but I humbly think you should focus on webRTC today as there is no timeline for availability of ORTC implementation.